# JavaScript - Variable/object as string and function at the same time

Tags: javascript, methods

Is it possible to create variable/object, which returns string and function at the same time?

```
> a
'Hello World'
> a()
2018-07-13T13:45:10.967Z
```

I've seen article about default methods of JavaScript objects, but I couldn't find it now.

I think it should be something like:

```
// Pseudo code
const a = {
    toString: "Hello World",
    function: () => new Date(),
};
```

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: @aquaballin did you mean do I test my _"code"_? :) Sure, but results is returned with: `a.toString` and `a.function()`. I'd like get values with `a` and `a()`.

Comment: You need to define a function a and then add a toString method to that function.

Comment: I am 100% sure that what you are trying to do is not possible, variables in Js can indeed assume different types, but you have to explicitly say that.

Comment: May be using Proxy? not sure though

Comment: Or possibly by creating a function first and then overriding toString of Function.prototype somehow to execute another function/statement that returns desired string.

Comment: No, it's not possible for a value to be a function and a primitive string at the same time. What do you need this for?

Comment: If this were possible I wonder what would print `console.log(typeof a)`;

Answer (score 1):

AFAIU this is only possible if, when you need the string, you use the variable in a way to enable explicit or implicit conversion, like this:

```js
const a = function () {
  return new Date()
};
a.toString = function() {
  return "Hello world";
}

console.log('' + a);
console.log(String(a));
console.log(a());
```

Comment: This only works with `console.log(String(a))`. Logging `a` alone will log the object.

Comment: @bergi thanks for pointing my error. I was led to believe it was ok because in SO's snippet if you run the code the output of `console.log(a)` outputs `Hello World`. As I tried outside of it I saw you were right. I corrected my answer.